# Deceleration sensor

Tags: sensor

I am looking for a component that gives electrical feedback when my device starts decelerating. It needs to be small (less than 1cm3 or close) and cheap. Are there any such components?

Edit: it should be analogue or just binary output and single axis.

Comment: what range of g and tolerance on -g threshold and is vibration in 3 axes? and how much in each axis? I know a 1$ solution but depends on answers to above. Also what object is this moving? and how is deaccelration controlled?

Comment: If you are still researching the situation, you may want to consider a generic (often multi-axis) accelerometer chip and a microcontroller to interpret it in ways that can be tuned and readily experimented with.  But if the requirement is very constrained, some sort of mass on a beam activating a switch type of assembly may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mentioned size constraints, I would not advise to go with a hand made hacky solution. The best option appears to be an accelerometer chip. If you are using a micro-controller already in your project, then I'd suggest you to go with i2c based digital ones because they appear to be cheap as compared to their analog counterparts.

In case there is no micro-controller already being used, analog acceleormeter makes sense. You can use some additional comparator circuit to give you a binary output for your desired cut-off acceleration levels.

As far as I know, binary output accelerometers are not available in the market because almost all applications will require knowing the acceleration value and not simply presence of acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an accelerometer. They are small and relatively cheap. They can have have analog or digital outputs. They generally report both acceleration and deceleration.